# when writing an if statement in PHP, is there a numbers equivalent to the string-length (strlen) function?

Tags: php, if-statement, numbers, strlen

I learned how to use the string-length function

```
<?php

$text = "this way";
if (strlen($text) > 5) { //characters
    echo "something";
}
```

and I want to use something like it that applies to number variables.

```
$text = 7;
```

What function would that be?

Comment: `if($text > 5)` - like that?

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433798/php-get-length-of-digits-in-a-number/28433988 it will show you how to count the digits in a number

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out how many digits are in a number?  `strlen()` will still work there.

Are you trying to record how many letters are in the string?  `$text_len = strlen($text);` will do that for you.

Comment: I wanted to know the value of the number.